# How to convert symbolic expressions to vectorized functions in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Can MatLab convert something like

```
syms t real
2*t^2+5*t+6
```

to

```
2.*t.^2+5.*t+6
```

automatically?

**Example**

```
syms t real
a=2;
v=int(a,t);
```

Now `v=2*t` so I want to convert it to `v=2.*t`.

Comment: Is the input `2*t^2+5t+6` stored as a string? Also, shouldn't that be `..5*t` instead in the input?

Comment: @Divakar: I have now edited the question.

Comment: You missed out on answering the first question.

Comment: I just edited my question. Please see my example. Does it answer your question?

Comment: How does the example correspond to what you are asking?

Comment: `v=2*t` so I want to convert it to `v=2.*t`. Is it clear now?

Comment: What output do you expect? symbolic expression, string or function handle?

Comment: You need [`matlabFunction`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html), not vectorization!

Comment: @knedlsepp I have included that in my answer (didn't see you had already commented on that). If you want to make your own answer I'll remove it

Comment: @LuisMendo: No need to remove it! (I recall reading *don't comment with an answer* in the FAQ anyway, so next time I'll abide by the rules again. ;-) )

Comment: @knedlsepp Ok. But now my answer is mostly based on your comments! :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo: Well, doesn't bother me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a **string**, you can do the replacing with [`regexprep`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html):

```
>> str = '2*t^2+5*t+6-3/t'
str =
2*t^2+5*t+6-3/t

>> str = regexprep(str, '([\*\^\/])', '.$1')
str =
2.*t.^2+5.*t+6-3./t
```

As you see, this changes all occurrences of `*`, `^` or `/` to their dotted versions.

If the string may already contain some dotted operators, modify the regular expression as follows to avoid double dots:

```
>> str = '2.*t^2+5*t+6-3./t'
str =
2*t^2+5*t+6-3/t

>> str = regexprep(str, '(?<!\.)([\*\^\/])', '.$1')
str =
2.*t.^2+5.*t+6-3./t
```

Or, as suggested by @knedlsepp, use the [`vectorize`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vectorize.html) function:

```
>> str = '2.*t^2+5*t+6-3./t'
str =
2.*t^2+5*t+6-3./t

>> str = vectorize(str)
str =
2.*t.^2+5.*t+6-3./t
```

---

If you have a **symbolic function**, use [`matlabFunction`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) to generate an [anonymous function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
>> syms t real
>> a=2;
>> v=int(a,t)
v =
2*t
>> v = matlabFunction(v)
v = 
    @(t)t.*2.0
```

so now

```
>> v(3)
ans =
     6
```

Comment: [`vectorize`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vectorize.html)! (Also deals with suddenly occurring `..`, after the replacement)

Comment: @knedlsepp Oh, _now_ I see what you mean!

Comment: Thanks. Your last answer was exactly what I was after.

Comment: @user172675 You should have said from the beginning that you were dealing with _symbolic_ expressions :-)